# How do I rebuild/repopulate the mysql.db table?

Tags: database, mysql

So I've been tasked with merging two similar but quite different Databases together consisting of multiple databases (lower case d). Through the course of this I'm also removing old databases from both Databases. I've already set them both up to have the same user privs, so that won't be an issue. What I notice that maybe a problem though is the mysql.db table. When I wrote and executed my scripts on a couple lab machines I notice that the mysql.db columns still show old databases that I had removed in the Db column. Any advice before I make this happen in production?

So far I've tried restarted the mysql daemon, truncating the table and restarting the daemon, and repairing the table... none of these worked.

Google isn't much help, searching for the mysql.db table is more difficult than it should be :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to go out and buy the book.  Short answer is MySQL reads from the `mysql.user` table first.  Since `mysql.user` is set up how we want it, the `mysql.db` table isn't super helpful.

Long answer, do it by hand on a per user per database basis if you can't just drop it and rely on your `mysql.user` table.

Make sure you flush privileges too!

Answer (score 0):

You should REVOKE privileges in order to delete records from the `mysql.db` table (and from other privilege tables).

Comment: The `mysql.user` table is set up correctly with the correct users.  I thought that my original grant statements (the first time when i created all new users) would have also updated the other mysql database tables.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but when granting privileges on databases, the only thing that will remove those privileges is a REVOKE query. Dropping related database won't change the records in `mysql.db`. In other words: if you create databases with the same names as the ones dropped - the old privileges that you didn't revoke will apply to the "new" databases.